count if occurrence is within 24 hours of any other occurrence
I have the following tables in BigQuery.
foo.disposition
enter image description here
foo.poc
enter image description here
Here's the query that's returning the total number of times that a phone number was dialed:
SELECT
        ANI_DIALNUM, COUNT(*) as Dialed_Frequency                                                                                                                                                                
FROM
(
        select ANI_DIALNUM FROM `foo.disposition`
        WHERE
                Skill_name like 'Support%IB%'
                AND parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', Start_Date) > '2024-01-01'
        union all
        select Contact_Name FROM `foo.disposition`
        WHERE
                Skill_name like 'Support%IB%'
        AND parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', Start_Date) > '2024-01-01'
) t                                                                                                                                                                                                              
WHERE
        ANI_DIALNUM NOT IN (select `Point of Contact` from `foo.poc`)
        AND NOT ANI_DIALNUM = '8.884157149E9'

GROUP BY ANI_DIALNUM
ORDER BY Dialed_Frequency desc

I have a query that returns the total number of occurrences of a match across two columns. It seems to work correctly. I now want to only count them if they occur within 24 hours. In other words, if a call happens and is from the same phone number more than 3 times per 24 hour period. The 24 hour period resets when a match is found. Whew.

Please Don't use images, share your data as text instead

you will want to use cte's instead of your sub-select to make it a bit easier to read, here is some untested code that will get you close:
with _raw ( --deal with sub-select first
   select ANI_DIALNUM,
          datetime_trunc(parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', Start_Date || ' ' || Start_Time), HOUR) AS callHour
   FROM `foo.disposition`
   WHERE Skill_name like 'Support%IB%'
         AND parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', Start_Date) > '2024-01-01'
   union all
   select Contact_Name,
          datetime_trunc(parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', Start_Date || ' ' || Start_Time), HOUR) AS callHour
   FROM `foo.disposition`
   WHERE Skill_name like 'Support%IB%'
         AND parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', Start_Date) > '2024-01-01'
), _cull as (
   select *
   from _raw
   where ANI_DIALNUM NOT IN (select `Point of Contact` from `foo.poc`)
         AND NOT ANI_DIALNUM = '8.884157149E9'
), _window as (
   select *, 
          count(*) over (partition by ANI_DIALNUM 
                         order by callHour
                         range between interval 24 hour preceding and current row
          ) as hour24count
   from _cull
)
select ANI_DIALNUM, count(*) as cnt
from _window
where hour24count >=3
group by 1
order by 2 desc

